# TLS 1.2 for Java 4 applications

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

I know that TLS 1.2 is not supported for applications build using Java 4.

But is there any work around available?

Comment: Why would you use Java 4 in **2020**?? It was released in **2002** (18 years ago!!!) and support has been cut in **2013**. So the work around for your problem is **PLEASE** upgrade your java version

Comment: It is an old application. Which now needs TLS 1.2 support

Comment: If you can't upgrade to the newest java version, I simply suggest upgrading to the first java version which supports TLS 1.2. The code that breaks may be limited to a few places.

Answer (score 3):

A distinct non-answer:

TLS is about securing communication. No Java4 application should communicate in ways that require "security" in 2020. That easy. Official support ended 2008.

Sure, if you have some tool somewhere that computes some data over night, and it still works, and that isn't connected to any network ... yeah, that is not good, but given reasonable isolation of that the corresponding machine: acceptable.

But the idea that you *connect* a Java4 system to the outer world is an absolute **no go**.

Thus the answer is: your problem isn't that your java4 thing doesn't talk TLS 1.2. Your real problem is that some people in your org consider it appropriate to connect a java4 application to something else.

Spend your time and energy in fixing that problem. Because the people that tell you to "work around" that TLS 1.2 thing, those are the people who will point at you in case there is a security breach.

Long story short: you are the engineer. Go tell your managers that their request is ridiculous, from the technical and the **business** point of view.

Rather assess whether you could simply run your old code on a newer JVM, or if it makes more sense to print out all the source code, pile it up, burn it up ... to then write the whole thing anew.